# In Javascript, convert string with UTC datetime into new Date() in specific time zone (ET always)

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

We have written the following function:

```
export function formatAMPM(dateString) {
    let date = new Date(dateString);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    let strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm + ' ET';
    return strTime;
}
```

And when called from my computer in Central European Time Zone, we get:

```
formatAMPM('2023-02-11 00:30:00+00:00')
'1:30 AM ET'
```

`'2023-02-11 00:30:00+00:00'` is a string with the date & time in UTC. We want to convert this to ET always, hence hard coding the `ET` in the string. However, because I am in CET time zone, the new Date() function is returning us a CET time, not an ET time.

This function should ideally be returning `7:30pm ET` for us, wherever it is called. How can we update this function to return always the ET time given the UTC string passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "ET" you mean Eastern Time in the USA (which uses either UTC-5 or UTC-4 depending on whether DST is in effect), you can get the desired output with the following:

```js
const s = new Date('2023-02-11T00:30:00Z')
  .toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    timeZoneName: 'shortGeneric',
    timeZone: 'America/New_York'
  });
console.log(s);
```

Notes:

- Your original input string `2023-02-11 00:30:00+00:00` *should* work, but it's not in the exact format [defined in the ECMAScript spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-date-time-string-format).  The separator should be a `T`, not a space.  (You can use either `Z` or `+00:00`, but generally you should use `Z` when referring to UTC.)
- You might have users from other parts of the world where AM/PM is not customary.  It would be better to pass `undefined` instead of `'en-US`, so that it formats with the user's locale instead of a fixed format.
- Refer to the docs for [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) and the available [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters) for more details.

Comment: I do mean Eastern Time. And the input string is something provided to us in our raw data, which is why I've used it in this format.

Comment: Yes it may be better to show in the users the time in their respective time zone

Comment: Locale and time zone are two different things.  Time zone is Eastern Time - or by identifier `"America/New_York"`.  Locale is `en-US`.   For example, you could still be displaying Eastern Time in the US but showing that value to a British English speaker (`en-GB`) who would find AM/PM meaningless because they're used to using 24-hour clock.  In other words, `19:30`.  They also wouldn't necessarily know what "ET" stands for.  Substitute `en-GB` above, and you'll get `"19:30 New York Time"` - which would be understood.

Comment: As another example, consider that you could be an English-speaking American visiting Japan.  In that case, your locale would be `en-US` and your time zone would be `Asia/Tokyo`.  They are completely orthogonal concepts.

Comment: "*Locale and time zone are two different things*" might be correct in the context of ECMA-402, but they shouldn't be. Locale, i.e. location, *should* infer a timezone. However the misappropriation of "locale" to mean "language" has warped reality. Similarly the use of "Eastern Standard Time" and "Eastern Daylight Time", which infer offsets, also causes confusion. Mix in the concept of IANA representative locations, which infer historic offsets based on date and location, and the concept of "timezone" needs considerably more explanation. ;-)

Comment: Oh, and if the OP really does want "ET" (i.e. -5:00) always, then Etc/GMT+5 or America/Coral_Harbour (which does not observe daylight saving) will do.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - when i replace `'en-us'` with `undefined` and remove `timeZone: 'America/New_York'`, I receive `1:30 AM Malta Time` as output. `Malta Time` is technically correct, but it seems to me like `CET` would be better to show than `Malta Time`?

Comment: The underlying data source is the [Unicode CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/) - which has very limited support for time zone abbreviations.  It will fall back to a short version of a full name when it can't resolve an abbreviation.